# Why can't I remove strange grey lines across my html

Tags: html, css

I am doing my first HTML and CSS for an entry at the coding school. I have strange grey lines that are going through my website. I assume they are connected with the section tags but I can't seem to remove them.

```
</header>
<section id=performances>
    <h2> Performances </h2>

.section {
  border:0;
}
```

Since I don't now exactly where the problem is here is a link to my project:

https://codepen.io/Laanna/pen/KjYjVX

Answer (score 0):

The strange lines are the `<hr>`. Just remove them.